# Django.Как выполнить поиск по параметру?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Возникло несколько вопросов по поиску в модели. Имеется стандартная форма с передаваемым параметром 'q' и следующая вьюха:

```
class PostList(ListView):
model = Post
context_object_name = 'post_list'
template_name = 'base.html'
paginate_by = 10
queryset = Post.objects.filter(relevance=True).order_by('-post_created')

def get_queryset(self):
    search_param = self.kwargs.get('q', None)
    if search_param:
        search_list = self.queryset.filter(title__contains=search_param)
        if search_list.exists():
            return search_list
        else:
            # пункт 4
    else:
        return self.queryset
```

1. как отфильтровать search_list, если в параметр 'q' передано несколько значений?
2. как в фильтре указать несколько полей модели, по которым необходимо искать? (в данном случе ищет только в поле title)
3. как исклюсить поиск, если параметр 'q' - это знаки пробела или табцляции? Подойдёт ли метод strip()?
4. можно ли добавить в это место (см. код) контекст для шаблона? Например если не удалось ничего найти в модели, в контекст шаблона передавлся бы словарик `{'search_error': "Соответствий не найдено"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(request):
    """Search for Posts"""
    filter_args = {}
    found_items_list = None

    search_param1  = request.GET.get('search_param1')
    search_param2  = request.GET.get('search_param2')
    ...
    search_paramN  = request.GET.get('search_paramN')

    if any((search_param1, search_param2, ... ,search_paramN)): 
        if search_param1:
            filter_args['title__contains'] = search_param1.strip()
        if search_param2:
            filter_args['relevance'] = search_param2
        ...

        if search_paramN:
            filter_args['somefield_somecondition'] = search_paramN

    found_items_list = Post.objects.filter(**filter_args).order_by('-post_created').distinct()
    return render(request, 'search_results_template.html', {'found_items_list':found_items_list,})
```